# Получить ширину элемента

Tags: css, bootstrap

```css
.red {
  background: red
}

.black {
  background: black;
  padding: 0 !important
}

.green {
  background: green
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100vh
}

form {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width:inherit
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 red">
      Текст
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 black">
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      <form>Форма ввода</form>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 green">
      Текст
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В контейнере есть форма ввода. Длина этой формы наследуют длину родителя, но только в коде. На самом деле выходит за пределы.

Это происходит из-за того, что у формы стоит position:fixed. Без него всё нормально. Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не нужно ничего пересчитывать на JS, используйте абсолютное позиционирование для формы. Или у вас она должна "ездить" по всему экрану?

Comment: @DaemonHK она должна быть зафиксирована снизу в центральном контейнере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        div {
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 bg-danger">
                Текст
            </div>
            <div class="col col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 bg-dark text-white">
                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            </div>
            <div class="col col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 bg-info">
                Текст
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="fixed-bottom">
            <form class="col-12 col-lg-6 m-auto p-2 bg-warning">
                <input type="text" class="btn-block form-control" />
            </form>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed позиционирует себя относительно окна просмотра. Видовой экран всегда остается фиксированным, поэтому вы получаете эффект, который вы делаете. При этом всякий раз, когда вы "наследуете" любую ширину, это будет соответствовать файлу просмотра.

Можна решить с помощью  `JS` или дать фиксированую ширину через `CSS`

```js
function fixedBlock(){
var parentwidth = $("div.black").width();      
      $("form.fixed").css('width', function(){
      return parentwidth
      });
    };
  $(document).ready(function(){
  fixedBlock();
 });
  $( window ).resize(function() {
  fixedBlock();
   });
```

```css
.red {
  background: red
}

.black {
  background: black;
  padding: 0 !important
}

.green {
  background: green
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100vh
}

form {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 red">
      Текст
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 black">
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      <form class="fixed">Форма ввода</form>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 green">
      Текст
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Страница загружается динамически,поэтому использовать JS не вариант

Answer (score 0):

Здесь можно (нужно) обойтись и без бутстрапа... поле ввода может просто незавсимо от родителя иметь ровно ту же ширину, что и родитель.

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.row-block {display: flex; justify-content: center;}

.center-block {
  width: 50%; max-width: 600px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black; color: #ddd;
}

.left-block {
  width: 25%; max-width: 300px;
  background-color: #c00;
}

.right-block {
  width: 25%; max-width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

.moo {
  margin: auto; left: 0; right: 0 /* - обеспечивают центрирование*/
  position: fixed; margin: auto; left: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%; max-width: 600px; height: 40px;
  background-color: #045acf; color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-block">
    <div class="left-block">
      Текст
    </div>
    <div class="center-block">
      Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
      <form class="moo">Форма ввода</form>
    </div>
    <div class="right-block">
      Текст
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так у вас форма выходит за границы центрального контейнера

Comment: @Olimp ES исправил... это из-за дополнительных маргинов здешнего редактора)

Comment: `Здесь можно (нужно) обойтись и без бутстрапа... ` - не могу, весь проект построен на Bootstrap

Comment: @OlimpES если весь проект построен на бутсрапе, то это не значит что нельзя без него....нужно только перестать юзать его классы и строить все на своих